# vim: 'Normal mode' Command to repeat last 'Command mode' command?

Tags: vim

is there any 'Normal mode' command to repeat last command runs in 'command-line mode'?

for example i move up a line in 'command-line mode' with `:m -2` and later i want to move up some other lines.
is there any normal mode to repeat `:m -2` without type `:@`  in 'command-line mode'.

Comment: For what it's worth, "normal mode" and "command mode" are synonymous. What you call "command mode" is actually called "command-line mode". See `:help vim-modes`.

Comment: synonyms u mean!

Comment: No. I mean synonymous, the adjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just hit `@:`.

See `:help @:` for help.